# Why the $username variable shows undefined but then dont shows error in if($username = request('createdBy')){?

Tags: php, laravel

Im not understanding the code that returns the posts created by a user when a specific url is acessed. I have two doubts.

First is, do you know how the variable `$username` exists in the " `if($username = request('createdBy')){`"? Right before it shows undefined.

The other doubt is, do you know how `$posts = $posts-get();`, if the user accesses “http://proj.test/posts?createdBy=john”, returns only the posts created by the user (as it should) and not all the posts of all users? Because inside the `if(username = request(createdBy))` the $posts variable is not overwriten with a new value, so the $posts value should not show all the posts of all users?

```
public function index(Category $category) 
{
    if($category->exists){
        $posts = $category->posts()->latest();
    }else{
        $posts = Post::latest();
    }
    dd($username); // shows Undefined variable: username

    if($username = request('createdBy')){
        dd($username); // shows john if the url is "http://proj.test/posts?createdBy=john"
        $user = User::where('name', '=', $username)->first();
        $posts->where('user_id','=', $user->id);
    }
    $posts = $posts->get();
    return view('posts.index', compact(('posts')));
}
```

Comment: use `==` or `===` in your if statement to do a check, rather than a reassignment

Comment: @Dorvalla, both are doing a check...  `==` or `===` in this case would result in an undefined error since `$username` isn't assigned yet..  The whole point of the `=` here is to assign the username variable and then check if it is truthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` is an assignment operator.  `$username` is assigned, then the `if` checks if the value of `$username` is truthy.

There's no reason to reassign the value of $post in the conditional block.  $post is a query builder object and `$post->where()` is mutating that object.

I recommend you read up on [operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php) and [objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) in the PHP manual.

Comment: Thanks, but so the if is "if($username = request('createdBy'))" is not necessary? Can´t be just "$username = request('createdBy')"?

Comment: It's the same thing as doing `$username = request('createdBy'); if ($username) { ...`.  What's inside the parentheses is evaluated first.